# Nuxt.js remove all css style link from head before render

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I want to remove all the style links from `head` section of nuxtjs app before rendering the page and add only one css file. I have a PurgeCSS script that will generate a file with only the css needed for a page.

Do you guys know where can I put my code to do this, If I put it in `mounted()` hook it makes the HTTP request already before removing the link.

```js
mounted() {
  const styleLinks = document.head.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]')
  styleLinks.forEach(link => link.remove());
}
```

**Current**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/25.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/11.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/50.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/37.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_nuxt/16.css">
```

**Desired**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/cdn/page.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add on created(){
}
hook,

alternatively,

Go to nuxt.config.js.
Refer the following template :
Good luck

```
head: {
    title: 'TCG',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
    //  { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href:
          'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha2/css/bootstrap.min.css',
      },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href:
          '/assets/fonts/stylesheet.css',
      },
    ],
```